# Pandas: overlay a column into row with a blank one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                dcc3   manager1   manager2
party_num                                 
L21635789  SBAS01030  A22677981        NaN
L21635789  SBAS02030        NaN  A22810282
L21635789  SBAS03030        NaN  A21721880
```

I'm trying to "overlay" one row (doesn't matter which) from manager2 that's present, into row that has manager1 that's blank/NaN like so:

```
                dcc3   manager1   manager2
party_num                                 
L21635789  SBAS01030  A22677981  A22810282
L21635789  SBAS02030        NaN        NaN
L21635789  SBAS03030        NaN        NaN
```

OR

```
                dcc3   manager1   manager2
party_num                                 
L21635789  SBAS01030  A22677981  A21721880
L21635789  SBAS02030        NaN        NaN
L21635789  SBAS03030        NaN        NaN
```

obvisously we need to reindex on DCC3, but then what?  It needs to only overlay these 2 columns (and only these columns as others exist)

I could really use the help, thanks you in advance.

#### EDIT 1:

I'm sorry I didn't clarify,  This is an elementary case.  There maybe cases where this is just a single value (where this doesn't apply), or up to 5-6.  I used 3 rows as an example.

Comment: did you try `manager1.ffill()`

Comment: Can you explain what your final desired result is?  Do you want the second two rows to be NaN for manager1 and manager2?

Comment: @JoeFerndz, No I have not.  Ill check that out

Comment: @B.Bogart, The final result is one of the 2 bottom results.  Notic how the first row has one from the same index below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines of code should solve the problem for you.

```
df.manager2 = df.manager2.bfill().ffill()
df.loc[df.manager1.isnull(), 'manager2'] = np.NaN
```

Below are a few scenarios I tried and the code is the same. See if this is what you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
c=['party_num','dcc3','manager1','manager2']
```

## Scenario 1:

**row 1: manager1 = NaN, manager2 = value**

**Results: assign manager2 value to row 2**

```
print ('\nScenario 1')
print ('row 1: manager 1: NaN, manager 2: value; pick row2 manager 1 value')
d  = [['L21635789','SBAS01030',np.NaN,'A22810282'],
     ['L21635789','SBAS02030','A22677981',np.NaN],
     ['L21635789','SBAS03030',np.NaN,'A21721880']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d,columns=c)
print (df)
df.manager2 = df.manager2.bfill().ffill()
df.loc[df.manager1.isnull(), 'manager2'] = np.NaN
print ()
print (df)
```

Output for Scenario 1:

```
Scenario 1
row 1: manager 1: NaN, manager 2: value; pick row2 manager 1 value
   party_num       dcc3   manager1   manager2
0  L21635789  SBAS01030        NaN  A22810282
1  L21635789  SBAS02030  A22677981        NaN
2  L21635789  SBAS03030        NaN  A21721880

   party_num       dcc3   manager1   manager2
0  L21635789  SBAS01030        NaN        NaN
1  L21635789  SBAS02030  A22677981  A21721880
2  L21635789  SBAS03030        NaN        NaN
```

## Scenario 2:

**row 1: manager1 = value, manager2 = NaN**

**Results: assign manager2 value to row 1**

```
print ('\nScenario 2')
print ('row 1: manager 1: value, manager 2: NaN; pick row2 manager 2 value')

d = [['L21635789','SBAS01030','A22677981',np.NaN],
     ['L21635789','SBAS02030',np.NaN,'A22810282'],
     ['L21635789','SBAS03030',np.NaN,'A21721880']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d,columns=c)
print (df)
df.manager2 = df.manager2.bfill().ffill()
df.loc[df.manager1.isnull(), 'manager2'] = np.NaN
print ()
print (df)
```

Output for Scenario 2:

```
Scenario 2
row 1: manager 1: value, manager 2: NaN; pick row2 manager 2 value
   party_num       dcc3   manager1   manager2
0  L21635789  SBAS01030  A22677981        NaN
1  L21635789  SBAS02030        NaN  A22810282
2  L21635789  SBAS03030        NaN  A21721880

   party_num       dcc3   manager1   manager2
0  L21635789  SBAS01030  A22677981  A22810282
1  L21635789  SBAS02030        NaN        NaN
2  L21635789  SBAS03030        NaN        NaN
```

## Scenario 3:

**row 1: manager1 = NaN, manager2 = NaN**

**row 2: manager1 = value; manager2 = NaN; row 3: manager2 = value**

**Results: assign manager3 value to row 2**

```
print ('\nScenario 3')
print ('row 1: manager 1: NaN, manager 2: NaN; pick row2 manager 1 & row 3 manager 2')

d = [['L21635789','SBAS01030',np.NaN,np.NaN],
     ['L21635789','SBAS02030','A22677981',np.NaN],
     ['L21635789','SBAS03030',np.NaN,'A21721880']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d,columns=c)
print (df)
df.manager2 = df.manager2.bfill().ffill()
df.loc[df.manager1.isnull(), 'manager2'] = np.NaN
print ()
print (df)
```

Output for Scenario 3:

```
Scenario 3
row 1: manager 1: NaN, manager 2: NaN; pick row2 manager 1 & row 3 manager 2
   party_num       dcc3   manager1   manager2
0  L21635789  SBAS01030        NaN        NaN
1  L21635789  SBAS02030  A22677981        NaN
2  L21635789  SBAS03030        NaN  A21721880

   party_num       dcc3   manager1   manager2
0  L21635789  SBAS01030        NaN        NaN
1  L21635789  SBAS02030  A22677981  A21721880
2  L21635789  SBAS03030        NaN        NaN
```

## Scenario 4:

**row 1: manager1 = value, manager2 = NaN**

**row 3: manager1 = value, manager2 = value**

**Results: ignore rows 1 and 2 as row3 has values for both manager1 and manager2**

```
print ('\nScenario 4')
print ('row 1: manager 1: NaN, manager 2: value; row3 has both manager 1 & manager 2')

d = [['L21635789','SBAS01030',np.NaN,'A21721880'],
     ['L21635789','SBAS02030',np.NaN,np.NaN],
     ['L21635789','SBAS03030','A22677981','A21721882']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d,columns=c)
print (df)
df.manager2 = df.manager2.bfill().ffill()
df.loc[df.manager1.isnull(), 'manager2'] = np.NaN
print ()
print (df)
```

Output for Scenario 4:

```
Scenario 4
row 1: manager 1: NaN, manager 2: value; row3 has both manager 1 & manager 2
   party_num       dcc3   manager1   manager2
0  L21635789  SBAS01030        NaN  A21721880
1  L21635789  SBAS02030        NaN        NaN
2  L21635789  SBAS03030  A22677981  A21721882

   party_num       dcc3   manager1   manager2
0  L21635789  SBAS01030        NaN        NaN
1  L21635789  SBAS02030        NaN        NaN
2  L21635789  SBAS03030  A22677981  A21721882
```

Comment: Very thorough.  Testing it now.

Comment: I think this will work, but it might need a groupby??? still looking at it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.where` to accomplish this:

```
df['manager2'] = np.where(df['manager1'].notnull() & df['manager2'].isnull(),
                          df['manager2'].dropna().iloc[0], np.nan) # You could do df['manager2'].dropna().iloc[1] for the other value
df
Out[1]: 
                dcc3   manager1   manager2
party_num                                 
L21635789  SBAS01030  A22677981  A22810282
L21635789  SBAS02030        NaN        nan
L21635789  SBAS03030        NaN        nan
```

Comment: I tried your code for scenario 2 in my option and found some challenges. Can you look into it and let me know what i am doing wrong pls?

Comment: @JoeFerndz good spot, we should use `.iloc[0]` instead of `[0]`

Comment: yes. it works now for all the conditions except Scenario 4. Since you are specifically looking at iloc[0], scenario 4 fails.

Comment: @JoeFerndz it's not failing because of `iloc`. It is failing because of the `np.where` condition that is: `df['manager1'].notnull() & df['manager2'].isnull()` I'm not sure if both of those conditions are required, but if not, then the op would just remove one of the two conditions OR change the `&` sign to an `|` sign.

Comment: Very close.  I'm really impressed.  I'm getting the first entry correct, but everything below is the just the first value (for the manager 2 column i.e: the first manager 2 value).